# How to abort a MR job inside a mapper (or a reducer)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to throw IOExceptions in the map method but the MR job is not stopped. The job will be stopped after tons of IOException thrown.
Is there any way to stop the whole job by just throwing an exception or some simple calls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an ideal use-case for Hadoop and not a good practice but you can kill your job right from inside your code.
So whenever you reach the condition where in you want your job to stop, log the needful and kill you job.

This can be done RunningJob.killjob() using the old `mapred` API or by using `Job.killJob()`. You should get reference to `RunningJob` or `Job` objects for the jobID in `configure()` or `setup()` respectively. And then call the kill job when you need, a pseudo code for new API would look as follows:

```
Class Map extends mapper<K1,V1,K2,V2>{
Job myJob;
@Override
setup(){
// Get the JObID
// Get the Job object
}

map(){
...
if(condition-to-stop){
myJob.killJob();
...
}
}
}
```

Comment: In the new API how do we get an instance of org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobID?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the getJobID method by simply overriding setup and run functions of the Mapper.

```
    public static class LineMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{
        boolean myCondition;

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context){
            myCondition = true;
        }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //something happens in your code and you change the condition to false to stop the mapper
            myCondition = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            setup(context);
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
                if(linecounter < 50) { 
                    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
                } else {
                    cleanup(context);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```