# how to terminate mapreduce job after checking for a condition?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I already found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998470/how-to-abort-a-mr-job-inside-a-mapper-or-a-reducer). But, As answer says it's unsafe to do so, is there any safer way to do this using new MapReduce library (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce)

Answer (score 0):

As I was willing to terminate the MapReduce job that runs in a loop; So, I solved this problem by using counters as follows,

```
public static enum SOLUTION_FLAG{
    SOLUTION_FOUND;
}
```

I took help from this site,

[How to use the counters in Hadoop?](https://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/)

From the value of a flag, I decided to if I can skip the task and when a job ends, at the end of each loop I checked for a value of this flag.

Let me know if I'm doing it correctly.